# JPA Repository - Query search if fields they are not filled

Tags: java, jpa

I need to do a Query for a set of fields, but only if they are filled or not null.

For example, I need to search all GuestsMetting for: GuestMeeting.created_at (interval of dates) and GuestsMeeting.group.id. But, if in the search box I only select a Group I will only "ignore" the interval of dates.

```
public class GuestsMeeting
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupId")
    private Group group;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "guestId")
    private Guest guest;
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonIgnore
    private Timestamp created_at;
}

public class Guest
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column
    private String email;
}
```

> ```
> @Query("select gm from GuestsMeeting gm inner join gm.group g  where (gm.created_at >= ?1 and gm.created_at <= ?2) and g.id = ?3")
> List<GuestsMeeting> findAll(Date startDate, Date endDate, long groupId);
> ```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named parameters in the query and use extra OR clause to check if named parameter is NULL. 
See below code as an example.

If

- startDate is not null - start date filter is used
- endDate is not null - end date filter is used
- (Optionally) groupId is not null - groupId filter is applied

```
@Query("select gm from GuestsMeeting gm inner join gm.group g 
where  
  (:startDate IS NULL or gm.created_at >= : startDate)  
and 
  (:endDate IS NULL or gm.created_at <= :endDate) 
and g.id = : groupId")
List<GuestsMeeting> findAll(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate, @Param("groupId") long groupId);
```